# Multiple images in picturebox c#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

How can I make several images to appear in one picturebox ?
P.S I have to update the images each 0.5-2 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the images onto an `Image` and load that `Image` into the `PictureBox`.

Comment: you'd probably have to run a parallel thread that has a timer, and after every x seconds, does what Fredrik says. Basically, load the picture onto an image object (say, img), and then pictureBox1.Image = img.